# When I run my flutter code I face the following Gradle Dependency problem. What should I do?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, compilation, dependencies

I have tried to solve it through different pre-answered questions on StackOverflow but they are not working, That is why asking here, Please help.

here is the problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\TME_Education\StudioProjects\jeda\android\app\build.gradle' line: 58

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Here is my dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
```

I was runing the code but this gradle Dependency eror happened.

Comment: try to did `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` after it.

Comment: I did and tried it before.

Comment: in the `dependencies` try to change the `compile 'com.android.tools.build:grade:7.12'` into `implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`

Comment: Open apps android project in android studio and do the updates.